# In ReactJS how can I use map() to create dropdown menus for each item?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I've been trying for hours to use `map()` in react to have each item in the iterable render a drop down list:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Card extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      showMenu: false,
    };

    this.showMenu = this.showMenu.bind(this);
    this.closeMenu = this.closeMenu.bind(this);
  }

  showMenu(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    this.setState({ showMenu: true }, () => {
      document.addEventListener('click', this.closeMenu);
    });
  }

  closeMenu(event) {

    if (!this.dropdownMenu.contains(event.target)) {

      this.setState({ showMenu: false }, () => {
        document.removeEventListener('click', this.closeMenu);
      }); 

    }
  }

  handleClick(arg){
      console.log("HEREw", arg)
      this.props.updateOptions(arg)
      console.log(this.props.Obj)
  }

  render() {
    //console.log("SUPPLIER", this.props)
    // for (lead in this.props.Obj.leads){}
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.Obj.leads.map(lead => (
        <a href={lead.first_name} onClick={this.showMenu}>
            {lead.first_name} {lead.last_name} 
            <br />
            <br />
        </a>

        ))}
        { 
          this.state.showMenu
            ? (
              <div
                className="menu"
                ref={(element) => {
                  this.dropdownMenu = element;
                }}
              >
                <button value="update" onClick={() => this.handleClick(true)}> Update </button>
                <button value="create" onClick={() => this.handleClick(true)}> Create </button>
              </div>
            )
            : (
              null
            )
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Card
```

The problem here is that the buttons `update` and `delete` don't appear under each item. They appear at the bottom of both of them. How can would I go about solving this?

Comment: useing "map" not suppose to help you with dropdowns, if you want dropdowns - you need to use "select" and "option" HTML tags

Comment: I think I've come to realize that the hard way, but I basically have a list of items. For each item I need to have a menu

Comment: i will recommend you to create a component for "lead", in this component you can place a menu logic

Answer (score 0):

Put your buttons inside the `leads.map` loop and make sure to give them each an id. That way they won't all behave as the same button.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've tried that but unless I put the buttons inside the <a> tags I get the error: `JSX tags must have one parent element`

Comment: React allows you to create a pretend element to deal with that error. Wrap your elements inside the following `<><\>`